# How can I compile typescript (1.6 or later) string to javascript string ? (Not file.ts to outputFile.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript

In general, How can I compile ts string to js string programmatically ?

By default, typescript compiler can compile ts file to js file.

How it works with string?

Comment: Place your `var foo: string = 'bar'` in a `string.ts` file, compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler don't support that. Check the compiler options [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options).

The only thing that I can suggest is to try to use the [Unix Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to transform the string into a file and pass it to the compiler but I can't promise you that it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Piping in Unix/Linux does not work for TypeScript compiler: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1226

However, there is a project on GitHub that tries to do what you want: https://github.com/teppeis/typescript-simple (don't expect latest version of TypeScript though)